# XSLT 2.0 - two pass processing

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

What I'd like to understand is the method of two pass, or multi-phase, processing and be able to apply it in my scenario below.

I'm still on my XSLT training wheels - most the content here has been assembled with help from colleagues, or from online sources, and modified to suit. Please forgive me if it's not clear or my understanding is flawed (any suggestions for improvement of the working parts are welcome too)

The XML below is a modified sample of my input xml. A single entry and the nodes of interest (plus a little fluff for context) are displayed below.

```
<root><nNumber id="N472131">
    <symbols>
        <symbol href="file:///U:/Labelling/Labels/Common Symbols/symbols with definitions/IP68_def.ai"/>
        <symbol href="file:///U:/Labelling/Labels/Common Symbols/symbols with definitions/Bin_2_def.ai"/>
        <symbol href="file:///U:/Labelling/Labels/Common Symbols/symbols with definitions/CE0197_def.ai"/>
        <symbol href="file:///U:/Labelling/Labels/Common Symbols/symbols with definitions/Recycle_def.ai"/>
        <symbol href="file:///U:/Labelling/Labels/Common Symbols/symbols with definitions/Humidity0-90_def.ai"/>
        <symbol href="file:///U:/Labelling/Labels/Common Symbols/symbols with definitions/Temp-10-55_def.ai"/>
    </symbols>
</nNumber></root>
```

My XSLT filters via a supplied parameter on @id and does a minor rearrange `@id` -> `<id></id>`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="search"></xsl:param>

<!-- Identity transform - copies all elements and attributes. -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Filter nNumber nodes by ID. -->
<xsl:template match="nNumber">
    <xsl:if test="@id=$search">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Convert the ID value from an attribute to an element under the nNumber node. -->
<xsl:template match="@id">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:include href="ApplyOrder.xsl"/>
```

The last line `<xsl:include>` runs a series of matches on the symbols tags to apply a predetermined order value (sample below)

```
<xsl:template match="symbol[@href='file:///U:/Labelling/Labels/Common Symbols/symbols with definitions/CE0197_def.ai']" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="order">111</xsl:attribute><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

The final piece of the puzzle is to order the symbol elements by their @order value (example below). I learnt the hard way that you can't apply the value and sort the applied value in the same operation.

```
<symbol order="111" href="file:///U:/Labelling/Labels/Common Symbols/symbols with definitions/CE0197_def.ai"/>
<symbol order="145" href="file:///U:/Labelling/Labels/Common Symbols/symbols with definitions/IP68_def.ai"/>
<symbol order="171" href="file:///U:/Labelling/Labels/Common Symbols/symbols with definitions/Humidity0-90_def.ai"/>
<symbol order="172" href="file:///U:/Labelling/Labels/Common Symbols/symbols with definitions/Temp-10-55_def.ai"/>
<symbol order="181" href="file:///U:/Labelling/Labels/Common Symbols/symbols with definitions/Bin_2_def.ai"/>
<symbol order="191" href="file:///U:/Labelling/Labels/Common Symbols/symbols with definitions/Recycle_def.ai"/>
```

So below is my attempt to inelegantly shoehorn Michael Kay's example of multi-phase processing into my current scenario.

I have the feeling I'm missing something pretty important and fundamental here - but I'm fairly oblivious to what it is...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="search"></xsl:param>

<!-- Identity transform - copies all elements and attributes. -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="phase-1"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Filter nNumber nodes by ID. -->
<xsl:template match="nNumber">
    <xsl:if test="@id=$search">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="phase-1"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Convert the ID value from an attribute to an element under the nNumber node. -->
<xsl:template match="@id">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:include href="ApplyOrder.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="phase-1-result">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="phase-1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$phase-1-result" mode="phase-2"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="phase-2">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="phase-2">
            <xsl:sort select="@order" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The result of the transform gives something altogether different (tags are absent, text is not from the relevant node etc..). I am happy to publish a sample if anyone thinks it will help (I'm conscious that I'm already taking up enough screen real estate)

NB: This workflow is for XML publishing using InDesign. However, the transform will be run in Oxygen v14.

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="search"></xsl:param>

    <!-- Identity transform - copies all elements and attributes. -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="phase-1">
        <!-- ---------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ... --->

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="phase-2">
        <!-- ---------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notes

- You mention template modes in your `<xsl:apply-templates>` but forgot to declare them on the actual templates.
- Why are you ordering attributes lexicographically by their *values*? Ordering attributes does not make any sense to begin with. They are supposed to be metadata. Don't bother ordering them, don't build anything that relies on attribute order.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My assumption was that applying a sort with `data-type="number"` resulted in a numerical order?

Is there an alternate method you would suggest for applying a sort on items with no sortable characteristics?

Comment: I'm not referring to the part that orders elements. I'm referring to the part that orders attributes.

Comment: The `href` attributes refer to images that are published in an order (I can't work around that).

Comment: That's still element ordering you are talking about. I mean this part `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="phase-2"><xsl:sort select="."/></xsl:apply-templates>`.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. To be honest, I have been using the sorting transform above without fully understanding how it works. I have been getting the results that I expected - but in two (originally three!) transforms.

Comment: Well, as I said. It processes attribute in value order. It would procude `<foo x="abc" y="def" />` and `<foo y="abc" x="def" />`. It's not a sensible thing do do. -- You've not told me if the rest of the answer works.